# Running Apache Tomcat 8 on port 80

Tags: linux, tomcat

I wants to install/configure apache tomcat on port 80 instead of 8080. I am running Nginx on port 80 and I made Nginx service stopped.

I changed Shutdown , Connector port from 8005 to 8008 and 8080 to 80 respectively. When I did use ./bin/startup.sh it shows no error and in catlina.out it says "org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1405 ms" but when i access http://localhost it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Suggest me If I am doing anything wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up a lot. Lets assume you want to use the non-root approach.

Use `authbind`, unless you want to use IP6.

Use `iptables` and redirect port 80 to 8080.

Setting up an Apache/Nginx as a reverse proxy takes longer and adds more complexity than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want tomcat to bind to a port lower than 1024, the short answer is that you'll have to run as root (on Unix systems). This is a particularly bad idea.

However, there are several ways around this.

One alternative is to have a regular webserver on port 80 (and 443) and use one of many ways to forward the traffic to tomcat. I'm not familiar with nginx, but there probably are ways to use it. On Apache httpd, you can use mod_jk, mod_proxy_ajp or mod_proxy_http to forward requests from Apache to tomcat. Of course, you would firewall tomcat, so that it can't be reached unless requests have gone through Apache.

If you only want to run tomcat and nothing else, you might want to look into [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html), which can start tomcat as root, then downgrade it to an unprivileged user once the port has been bound. Check the comments: I've never used it and at least @raupach has an argument against it (its age). You could also simply use iptables to forward port 8080 to port 80. However, you should check if this makes tomcat realize that it's getting requests on port 80: If tomcat still believes its answering on 8080, it will generate URLs that hit 8080 instead of 80 - iptables is another technique that I've never used.

The first option to configure (reverse proxy) is more work but has several more advantages - e.g. you have mod_rewrite and other goodies at your disposal. I like it a lot better than jsvc. You can also have static files being served through Apache, without bothering tomcat. This can easily be step 1 in your performance tuning.

Comment: Good luck with jsvc. It is old and I haven't seen it in deployment in years.

Comment: You're right - I've mentioned it due to "nothing else being involved". I'll reorder my answer. In fact, I'm so strongly preferring the reverse proxy solution that I am only aware of jsvc, but have never considered using it myself. And thinking more about it than yesterday when I quickly answered this question, iptables is yet another option

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to run catalina.sh as a non-root user. You **cannot** bind to port 80 as a regular user.

However, this shouldn't be a problem if you are using your distro's provided tomcat package.